# HTML/CSS - What rules should I set to get this proper alignment?

Tags: css, html, icons, font-awesome

Here is an image that illustrates my goal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uver4.jpg

What would be the best way to achieve a style that looks like this? By this, I am asking, how can I set up rules so that the spacing and locations of the buttons are perfectly aligned in the center (they are not aligned correctly right now). I was thinking of a div that wraps the whole thing together, a div that floats left holding the first angle and the title, and a second div that floats left holding the icons. The icons are from the font-awesome package and I do not understand how to align them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its hard to answer it exactly unless you post what you currently have.
However, your on the right track.

What I would do:

- Wrap the whole thing in a div (as you said)
- float the text left (which you said as well)
- float the icons **right** (not left)

As far as spacing, put a margin/padding left/right to the two buttons.

EDIT:
As per my discussion with Luiz Berti:

You are almost right.
Try this instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYPK5/1/

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="text">Lots of stuff here</div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/led24.de/led/16/page-white-edit-icon.png" />
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/led24.de/led/16/bin-closed-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
.buttons img {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should do:

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="first button"></div>
    <dic class="second button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar{
    width: 960px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; /* This is what will centralize it vertically and horizontally */
}

.first { background-image: url('image.png') }
.second { background-image: url('image2.png') }
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Im sure they want the button clickable. (Hence "BUTTONS") So, they would still have to go through shenanigans to properly align a few A tags (or whatever method they decides to go about this). Therefore, it would probably be easier to just use it as an img. Not a background. Just my personal opinion though. Everyone has different tastes

Comment: If an img tag were to be used the only difference in the code would be to add a `display: block;` in `.button`, change `height` to `50px`, `margin` to `5px 10px 5x 5px`, add a `border: none` and it should be ok.

Comment: Why would you explicitly add a `display:block`. It would be pointless/counter-intuitive with a float. Besides, it would throw more alignment off. A block is meant to take up the entire room allotted. So while, yes, you COULD add a `display:block` you would need to do extra to get THAT positioned correctly

Comment: The default display for an `img` tag is `inline-block`, which would make really hard to work with the other properties, however you have a point, when you declare a `float` it automatically turns into a `block`. Not sure why you are being so rude though.

Comment: Not trying to be rude. Trying to inform. The imgs could be within their own div. THAT div has a set width. The imgs could then, take as much room as they would like. However, there is still a difference between `inline` and `block`.

Comment: I will have an update to my answer shortly. I typing up a jsfiddle to demonstrate, which will also, hopefully solve the OP's problem as well.

Comment: Adding another `div` just to wrap the `img` is pointless and redundant. The `img` tag itself can serve the purpose of a `div` without the need of a wrapper. Also, there is `inline`, there is `block` and there is `inline-block`. The `img` tag's default is the latter, which you completely forgot on your tiny rant. There is no need to be rude to inform somebody of anything, you just choose to. Before criticising my answer why don't you go and fix your extremely vague one.

Comment: "Before criticising my answer why don't you go and fix your extremely vague one." Now isn't that what I just said I would do. ;-) Again, your taking things out of context. Im not trying to be rude.

Comment: Blah. Its time for me to go to bed. Its been a long day. I did this on another thread as well. After re-reading your answer, I guess we pretty much did do the same thing. My brain to totally fried by this point. So, once again, wasnt trying to be rude. Lol. I guess Im done for the night